# Catch contents of PHP session under Apache with Python (mod_wsgi)?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Is there a way to catch the contents of the PHP session variable `$_SESSION['user_id']` with a `mod_wsgi` Python script? I'm running a script in the background that will decide whether or not the user may proceed to view the document.

I would like to do something like this:

```
def allow_access(environ, host):
    allow_access = False

    if environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] == 'forbidden_dir':
        if session['user_id'] == '1':
            allow_access = True

    if allow_access:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Is it possible?

Comment: do you use both php and python on the server?

Comment: FYI. SCRIPT_NAME is not available from mod_wsgi access hook. You would need to use Location directive in Apache configuration to restrict access hook to a specific URL context.

Comment: SilentGhost: Yes, the application is written in PHP because I started to learn Python after I started to write the app.

Comment: Graham: Could you point me to any tutorials on using the access hook? The official docs didn't provide much info :)

Comment: Location and Directory directives are Apache directives, so you need to see Apache documentation for how to use Location directive. BTW, you also should not check REQUEST_URI in an access hook either as it is unprocessed form and any checks against it could fail if expecting it to always be a certain value unless you are going to perform all the HTTP decoding of it first. If you feel that available documentation isn't enough, then use the official mod_wsgi list on Google groups referenced from the mod_wsgi site to ask questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's possible, it's not easy; apache stores session variables in files in a special format.

Your best option might be to write a php page that prints all session variables. (Hard-code it to only serve to localhost.)  Open the url to that page from within your python script.  Add a header to the url request with the session info.  Then, once the php page is loaded in Python, parse the input.

Comment: I think you will definitely need to have Python call your PHP pages as the $_SESSION vars are really an artifact of PHP, rather than Apache.

Comment: Aha, that would probably work well. I can see the solution clearly :)

Answer (score 3):

please don't do this:

```
if allow_access:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

when you can do: `return allow_access`.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what I was thinking. :/